# How I ignore json values while selecting from table?

Tags: sql-server-2019

My **Comments** table has a column **replies** ( type- nvarchar(max)) where I've putted all the replies. It is a array of json, like

```
[
{
  "Name":{
     "First":"Peter",
     "Last":"Vogel"
  },
  "Text":"Hi",
  "Date":"2017-09-30"
},
{
  "Name":{
     "First":"Jan",
     "Last":"Irvine"
  },
  "Text":"Hello",
  "Date":"2015-01-14"
}
]
```

I don't want to get the date while selecting from **Comments**. How can I do that?

I've tried a solution like,

```
 select  new_replies = JSON_MODIFY([replies], '$[0].date', null)
```

But this set `NULL` in date field for only the first reply, not for all.

Comment: What is your expected output and what have you tried so far? Also note, that this JSON content is not valid.

Comment: why it's tagged with both `sql-server` and `mysql-json`? what's your rdbms? what's the type of the column `replies`?

Comment: SQL Server has `JSON_MODIFY` function. Are you sure about the `mysql-json` tag?

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the question properly. It's SQL Server 2019 and the type of replies is nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_MODIFY()` expects the index of an array item to modify it's content and I don't tnink that you can use a wildcard in this situation. But an approach, based on a combination of `OPENJSON()` and string aggregtaion is an option:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Comments
FROM (VALUES (N'[
{
"Name":{
    "First": "Peter", 
    "Last": "Vogel"
}, 
 "text": "Hi", 
 "date": "017-09-30"
},
{
"Name":{
    "First": "Jan", 
    "Last": "Irvine"
}, 
 "text": "Hello", 
 "date":"2015-01-14"
}
]')
) v (Replies)
```

Statement (for SQL Server 2017+):

```
SELECT NewReplies = (
   SELECT CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.date', NULL), ','), ']')
   FROM OPENJSON(Replies)
)   
FROM Comments
```

Statement (for SQL Server 2016):

```
SELECT NewReplies = CONCAT(
   '[',
   STUFF(
      (
      SELECT ',' + JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.date', NULL) 
      FROM OPENJSON(Replies)
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
   ),
   ']'
)   
FROM Comments
```

Result:

```
NewReplies
-----------------------
[{
"Name":{
    "First": "Peter", 
    "Last": "Vogel"
}, 
 "text": "Hi"
},{
"Name":{
    "First": "Jan", 
    "Last": "Irvine"
}, 
 "text": "Hello"
}]
```

Comment: could you please share the similar query for sql server 2016?

Comment: @shohagsarkar The answer is updated. `STRING_AGG()` is available from SQL Server 2017, so for the previous versions you need to use the `FOR XML PATH` approach for string aggregation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working like a charm.